# GtkAlignment can only contain one widget at a time

Tags: c, gtk, glade, gtk2

I made a GUI in Glade. I have this kind of structure:

_ A GtkWindow named winTimer
__ A GtkVBox
___ A GtkHBox
____ A GtkAlignment called alignTimer with absolutely **nothing** inside.

[My structure (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Ofd.gif)

I do:

```
controlli->alignTimer=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"alignTimer"));
controlli->pbTimerComposito = gdk_pixbuf_new(GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,0,8,320,200);
controlli->imgTimer = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(controlli->pbTimerComposito));
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(controlli->alignTimer),controlli->imgTimer); /* warning */
gtk_widget_show(controlli->imgTimer);
```

Where *controlli* is a pointer to a struct that has, among other things:

```
GtkWidget *alignTimer;
GdkPixbuf *pbTimerComposito;
GtkWidget *imgTimer;
```

I get this at runtime:
**Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkAlignment, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkAlignment can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains
a widget of type GtkImage**

But that is not true! It's the first and only widget that I'm adding! What's happening? I had done the exact same thing in another part of my app and it's been working perfectly for years.

My environment:
- Windows XP SP3
- MinGW
- GCC 4.8.1
- GTK 2.24.10

PS I know I'm using an old version of GTK, deprecated widgets and an ancient OS, but I code just for fun so I'm OK with that. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: _alignTimer with absolutely nothing inside_ To sort this out, you could test with [`gtk_bin_get_child()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkBin.html#gtk_bin_get_child) if there really is nothing inside (and if not what it is). (I've used for a long time gtkmm (based on GTK+ 2.4) on Windows and never saw something strange like this. However, I must admit that I never used glade nor have any experience with this.)

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I spotted the problem: the function with the code above was called twice! Thanks Scheff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved (or, rather, there was no problem).
The function that contained the code I posted above was called twice.  Facepalm for myself.